# Execute git commands in python and configure credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, subprocess

I am working on some script where in I generate a CSV file and I need to upload that file to a repository using python script.

Here is how I have files in my linux directory now

```
Project_Repo_Details.csv -> file
repo1-> Directory
script1.py
script2.py
```

so repo1 is my folder created when I cloned my repository in linux. Now I need to write script to move my csv file to that repo and need to execute below commands.

```
git add .
git commit -m "adding file"
git push origin master
```

Also one more problem is while executing this commands it asks for credentials also. I tried to use subprocess like below:

```
import subprocess
import os

def movefileAndPush():
    os.rename('Project_Repo_Details.csv','repo1/Project_Repo_Details.csv')
    
    subprocess.Popen("cd repo1")
    subprocess.Popen("git add Project_Repo_Details.csv")
    subprocess.Popen("git commit -m PCV-99 adding repo report")
    subprocess.Popen("git push origin master")
```

This script just ran and nothing happened. Please help me in completing this script.

Comment: Use `subprocess.run()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()`?

Comment: You may also need to split up the arguments. Please read the subprocess documentation, which has various examples showing its usage.

Comment: As to the credentials: git can accept credentials from an external file, which is probably a better way if you're scripting things than putting the credentials into the script or querying them each time.

Comment: You could also consider using a bash script for this part: it is likely to be easier for this set of commands.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I used os.chdir() to point things to a specific directory and subprocess.run to execute commands and I passed username and password in git push command.
It worked awesome :)

```
import subprocess
import os

def movefileAndPush():
    try:
        x = subprocess.run(['cp','Project_Repo_Details.csv','bitbucket_repo_report/Project_Repo_Details.csv'])
        print(x.stdout)
        print(x.stderr)
        os.chdir("/dirs/Repo-report_scripts/bitbucket_repo_report")
        subprocess.run(['git','config','--global','user.email','test@gmail.com'])
        subprocess.run(['git','add','Project_Repo_Details.csv'])
        subprocess.run(['git','commit','-m','PQR-99 adding repo report'])
        subprocess.run(['git','push','https://username:password@gitreporul','--all'])
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occured :".format(e))
if __name__ == '__main__':
   movefileAndPush()
```